# Vowels in a String are in Alphabetical Order

Tags: java, strings, programming-challenge

## Task

Write an implementation that returns whether a `String` has vowels (English language) in alphabetical (A-Z) order or not.

## Feedback

- Is my `vowels` variable appropriate? Is there a better way to implement a vowel lookup?
- If a candidate `String` has no vowels, the validator will return `true` - is that reasonable? From a logical perspective, the program isn't lying, but you could make the same argument if it returned `false`. Would it be better to return an exception - something like `NoVowelsInCandidateException`?

## Implementation

```
public class VowelOrderValidator {
    private static final List<Character> vowels = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y')
    );

    public static boolean areVowelsOrdered(final String candidate) {
        final char[] chars = candidate.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
        int lastVowelIndex = 0;
        for (final char c : chars) {
            final int lookupIndex = vowels.indexOf(c);
            if (-1 != lookupIndex) {
                if (lookupIndex < lastVowelIndex) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    lastVowelIndex = lookupIndex;
                }
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side-note, matching the lowercase candidate against the following regular expression would work :) : `"[^aeiouy]*(?:a[^eiouy]*)?(?:e[^aiouy]*)?(?:i[^aeouy]*)?(?:o[^aeiuy]*)?(?:u[^aeioy]*)?y?[^aeiou]*"` (but I find it really less readable!)

Comment: Not a review, but I suggest Java 8, in cases like this it cuts down a ton of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Since `vowels` is a constant for your program, the convention would be that its name is in all uppercase, like `VOWELS`.
- Take great care when uppercasing Strings:

  ```
  final char[] chars = candidate.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
  ```

  Uppercasing a String [depends on the locale](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11063102/1743880). By not specifying a locale, you are relying on the default locale of the JVM, which may cause problems for Turkish users (for example). It would be better to specify the [`ROOT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ROOT) locale:

  ```
  final char[] chars = candidate.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT).toCharArray();
  ```
- I'm not a big fan of inversing the conditions in an `if`:

  ```
  if (-1 != lookupIndex) {
  ```

  The following would be easier to read:

  ```
  if (lookupIndex != -1) {
  ```

  In fact, it would be even better to not check against `-1` but test that the result is positive:

  ```
  if (lookupIndex >= 0) {
  ```

  It decouples the fact that [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) returns `-1` from what you really want to test, which is that the index was found.
- I think returning `true` when there is no vowels is the least surprising result: when there are no vowels, then they all are in the right order. Throwing an exception would be a bad idea: no vowels in a String is not a real exceptional condition.